# Consumo de una api GET en android

Tags: java, android-studio, api, get, response

Estoy tratando de consumir una api get en android studio.
Esto es lo que tengo en mi api interface

```
 @GET("convert?to=MXN&from=USD&amount=1")
    @Headers({"Content-type:text/plain","apikey:NWwDqW5QfiuKQPt9ROyaYm279TaJTlG2"})
    Call<Consul> Consulta(@Query("to") String to,
                          @Query("from") String from,
                          @Query("amount") String amount);
```

Mi modelo de la api esta de la siguiente manera

```
    private String success;

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }
```

Consulto la api de la siguiente manera

```
    private void calcular() {
        ApiInterface api = ApiConsultas.getApiService();
        Call<Consul> call = api.Consulta("MXN","USD","1");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Consul>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Consul> call, Response<Consul> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String i = response.body().getSuccess();
                    System.out.println("Consulte " + i);// NOPMD
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Consul> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Falla", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Adjunto foto de lo que me arroja cuando lo corro ya que no me trae el resultado de success, pero si hace la consulta, creo que es en mi model el problema pero no se como corregirlo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto error al imprimir  t.printStackTrace(); en onFailure()
El error que arroja es:

Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 3 column 15 path $.query

Adjunto imagen de mi modelo completo abajo solo estan sus getter aun setter
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en onFailure() imprime el mensaje de error, t.printStackTrace(); es importante imprimir esta información para saber que sucede, de otra forma puedes tardar mucho tiempo en determinar el problema. Agrega el mensaje de error en tu pregunta.

Comment: Listo, he agregado el error que arroja

Comment: Agrega como texto lo que arroja, ya que los logs o código como imágenes puede no ser visible para la comunidad.

Comment: Listo, me di cuenta que es la manera de llamar a query e info, ya que si los omito en el model si me lo muestra sin problemas ¿Debo llamarlos con un array?

Comment: Cuál es la API que estás usando?, el problema es que estás recibiendo una respuesta json.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se muestra en el error:

> Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 3 column 15 path
> $.query

indica que se esperaba como respuesta una cadena pero se recibió un objeto json, esto lo puedes ver en la respuesta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debes revisar la documentación de la API de como obtener la respuesta requerida.

Comment: Si le devuelve un json entonces podría usar [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) para convertirlo a el modelo que tiene.

Comment: Si!, @javdromero sería una buena opción.

Comment: Muchas gracias, hasta el momento va resuelto alojando el resultado de esos dos campos en un JsonObject